# If $ \lim n\tan{\frac{180°}{n}}= \pi $, is $ \infty \times0 = \pi $?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, infinity, pi

I derived the volume of a cone using two approaches and compared the results.

First I integrated a circle of radius $r$ over the height $h$ to get the expression: $$V_1=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h$$

Then I considered a polygonal pyramid of infinite sides.

An n-sided polygon with apothem $r$ has an area of: $$A=nr^2\tan{\frac{180°}{n}}$$

Integrating this over the height $h$ gives the expression for the area of the n-sided polygonal pyramid as: $$V_2=\frac{1}{3}n\tan{\frac{180°}{n}}r^2 h$$

Equating $V_1$ and $V_2$ implies that: $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n\tan{\frac{180°}{n}}\right) = \pi $$

So is it true to say that: $$\infty\tan{\frac{180°}{\infty}} = \pi$$

But: $$\tan{\frac{180°}{\infty}}=0$$

So: $$\infty (0)=\pi$$

Can anyone shed some light on this surprising result?

Comment: You can use analogous calculations to show that $\infty \cdot 0 = x$ for any $x$. This is basically the reason we don't do real arithmetic with infinities.

Comment: Indeed, $\lim_{n\to\infty} n \frac{x}{n} = x$. Since $\tan (180^\circ/n) = \tan(\pi/n)$ “looks like” $\pi /n$ for large $n$ (to see this, find the tangent line to $\tan(x)$ at $0$), we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}n \tan(\pi /n)=\pi$.

Comment: The numbers different from $0$ can be multiplied by and can divide any number. The number $0$ is more restricted. It can multiply any finite number, but it can't divide any finite number. The number $\infty$ is even more restricted. It can't multiply $0$, it can't divide itself. It can't subtract itself.

Comment: The whole reason we write $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n\tan{\frac{180}{n}}\right) = \pi$$ is because it is risky to use $\infty$ lazily as a number: $$\infty\tan{\frac{180}{\infty}} = \pi$$ which is meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Equating $V_1$ and $V_2$ implies that: $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n\tan{\frac{180}{n}}\right) = \pi $$

That is correct.  180 degrees is $\pi$ radians.  If you change variables from $n$ to $\theta$ with $\theta = \frac{1}{n}$, you get
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n\tan{\frac{180}{n}}\right)
 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\tan{\pi x}}{x} 
$$
and that is, in fact $\pi$.

> So is it true to say that: $$\infty\tan{\frac{180}{\infty}} = \pi$$

Not at all.  The limit of a product of functions is the product of the limits of the functions *provided those functions have limits in the first place*.  Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} n$ does not exist, you cannot apply the limit laws that way.

In short: $\infty$ is not a number.  Treating it as a number leads to madness (or, at least, contradiction).

Answer (score 8):

This is not a "result". $\infty$ is not a number. If your argument were correct you could use it this way:

For all positive integers $n$
$$
n \times \frac{1}{n} = 1.
$$
Then taking the limit as $n \to \infty$
$$
\infty \times 0 = 1.
$$

Comment: ... and the same with any other number in place of $1$ throughout the argument.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Indeed.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot simply replace expressions that tend to infinity by that same symbol; then you would lose information on how fast something tends to infinity, for example.

Take $a_n=n$, $b_n=2n$. Then clearly, both tend to infinity. But $b_n/a_n=2\to2$, and $a_n/a_n=1\to1$. Both limits would be "$\infty/\infty$", but are still very different. What is key here is the *way* both expressions tend to infinity. You lose this information when you just replace the sequence with a $\infty$ symbol.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n\tan{\frac{180°}{n}}) = \pi$

Take $\frac{1}{n}= x$, then ${n \to \infty} \implies {x \to 0}$

Also we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{\tan x}{x}} = 1$$

So $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n\tan{\frac{180°}{n}}) = \pi \implies \lim_{x \to 0} ({\frac{\tan 180° x}{180° x}}180°) = \pi \implies 180°=\pi$

Comment: When OP writes $\tan \frac{180}{n},$ I am assuming OP really means $\tan_0 x = \tan \frac{\pi x}{180}.$ Which is to say, tangent with degrees rather radians as the argument unit.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, $\infty\cdot0$ has no precise value (not counting that it is a mathematically "illegal" expression).

For more rigor, you can work with limits and write

$$\infty\cdot0=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)g(n)$$ where $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}g(n)=0$.

Then you have the following examples:

- $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=\tan\dfrac1n\implies \infty\cdot0=1,$
- $f(n)=n^2$ and $g(n)=\tan\dfrac1n\implies \infty\cdot0=\infty,$
- $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=\tan\dfrac1{n^2}\implies \infty\cdot0=0,$
- $f(n)=n^3$ and $g(n)=\dfrac1n-\tan\dfrac1n\implies \infty\cdot0=-\dfrac13$
- $\cdots$

---

In your case,

$$\tan°\frac{180°}n=\tan\frac\pi n$$ where the second tangent function has its argument expressed in radians. Then for small arguments,

$$\tan\frac\pi n\approx \frac\pi n$$

so that

$$n\tan\frac\pi n\approx \pi$$ and this is exact in the limit.

Comment: I tried to put quotes around $\infty\cdot0$ to stress that this expression is invalid. But the quotes were too ugly.